# Slider images change on mobile chooses desktop images if value is empty

Tags: php, html, jquery, mobile, slider

On mobile screen my slider images change but if value is empty then it chooses desktop images automatically why?

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    var width = $(document).width();
    if (width < 500) {
       
      $('.mobile_img').each(function (i, el) {
        console.warn(el);
        var img = $(el).val();
        //alert(img);
        //$(el).parent('li').remove();
        if (!$(el).val() == "")
        {         
          $(el).parent('li').css("background-image", "url(" + img + ")");
        }
        else{
           $(el).parent('li').remove();
        }
        
       
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). You can get images from placeholder.com

Comment: Hi, i am not sure to understand what is "el" and if you have a variable why you use jquery selector $() on a variable

Comment: Also images do not have values